# jquery clear the validate error message on reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jquery-plugins

I have a JSP as follows:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jquery/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

//......


....///
$("#apiID").validate({
rules: {
    pinNbr: "required",
    TranDt: "required"
},
messages: {
    pinNbr:"Please enter a Pin number.",
    TranDt: "Please enter tran date."
    }
}); 

$("#resetId").click(function () {
  var validator = $('#apiID');
  validator.resetForm();
});
});

</script>

<form:form id="apiID" action="executeApi.do" commandName="apiForm">

//..

<DIV class="label">Pin Number:&nbsp;</DIV><DIV class="nonLabel"><form:input path="pinNbr" maxlength="50" size="40" /></DIV>
<DIV class="label">Todays Transaction:&nbsp;</DIV><DIV class="nonLabel"><form:input path="TranDt" size="10" maxlength="10" />

..//

<DIV class="btn-group">
        <button id="submitId"  type="submit" class="default-button">Submit
        </button>
        <button id="resetId"  
            type="reset" class="default-button">Reset
        </button>
    </DIV>
</form:form>
```

When I do not enter values for pinNUmber and TranDt I get error message inline with the input field using `validate()`. Once the click reset I want the inline error messages to disappear. The `resetForm()` resets the values in all the input fields button but not the error message. Button reset resets the path variables but not these error messages.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
form.find('label.error').remove();
```

update 1 :

try to add this line to your code after `validator.resetForm();` `form.find(".error").removeClass("error");`

Comment: ddint help. used this as my first line inside reset fuction and then called reserform. this line didnt change anything howvere reset form cleared input fields.

Comment: can you try this : $(".cancel").click(function() {
   validator.resetForm();
 )};

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: tried $('label[id*="error"]').text('');
and it worked. Thanks much